# monitor the value of a variable for some time

Tags: python-3.x

I am measuring the power value of a phase of a system from a meter via serial rtu modbus communication.
I'm trying to write a code that allows me to monitor the power value within a certain value, for example + - 5%. If the instantaneous power value read remains within that range of values ​​for 15 min then I take it as valid data, otherwise if before the expiry of the 15 minutes this value leaves that range I must reset the timer to 15. 
if you know any library that monitors the value of the variables it would be very useful to me. 
Thanks

Comment: you do not need a library for this. just create a while-loop that expires after x-amount of seconds. Take the current time, add 15min as a condition, and break after that.

Comment: yes that part was easy, but the main part is to detect the changing of the value of the variable in a certain range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any external libraries.

Depending if you just want to run this in your script, or if you have more things that needs to run, you could opt to make it `async`. Try something like this:

```
import datetime
import asyncio    


def resetTimer(duration: float):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    expire = now + datetime.timedelta(0,0,0,0, duration)
    return expire

async def monitor(durationMinutes: float, variableToCheck: float) -> None:
    lowerThreshhold = variableToCheck * 0.95
    upperThreshhold = variableToCheck * 1.05
    expire = resetTimer(durationMinutes)

    while datetime.datetime.now() >= expire:
        if variableToCheck >= upperThreshhold or variableToCheck <= lowerThreshhold:
            expire = resetTimer(durationMinutes) # resets timer
        else:
            # do something else if value stays within range the entire duration
```

Usage:

```
task1 = asyncio.create_task(
    monitor(15, myVariable)
)
await task1
```